# javascript: Refactor global objects to require() modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependency-injection, browserify

I want to modernize our JavaScript architecture -- and more importantly, begin writing unit tests for our JavaScript code.

I have been piecing information together from different questions/blogs, and have a tentative plan in place. However, I'm really not certain if I'm on the right track.

## The Plan:

1. Refactor components as exported modules instead of global objects.
2. Create a single entry point (index.js?) that *requires()* all files/components.
3. User Browserify to create my browser-compatible static file (back to global).
4. Using node, mocha, & chai, run *npm test* to execute tests which reference the exportable components.

## The Refactor:

Global objects:

```
// myProject.js
// --------------------
var MyProject = {};

// component1.js
// --------------------
myProject.component1 = {};
```

to require() modules:

```
// myProject.js
// --------------------
var component1 = require('./component1');
modules.export = { component1 };

// component1.js
// --------------------
var component1 = {};
modules.exports = component1;
```

## The Question:

If a project uses global objects to namespace components, how could I refactor these JavaScript files to export modules that will work in node? Is the above plan following modern standards for JavaScript dependencies/modules?

My main concern is that my index.js (or main entry) file will become a maintenance nightmare (adding every new file as require()).

Comment: Your `index.js` should only require core entry-points (like top-level components).  Other files will be required indirectly.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks for pointing that out. Being new to using require() I didn't even realize I could rely on the components boiling everything up. Thank you x1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index.js should only require core entry-points (like top-level components).

Other files will be required indirectly.

Therefore, you shouldn't have any *giant lists of all files*; each file should only require things that it directly uses.

Browserify will assemble a transitive closure of all require()d files.

Comment: Thanks for posting this an answer - it definitely resolved my main concern with the approach. Can I also take this to mean that the rest of my plan is solid on the other bullets, in your opinion? I'm open to any suggestions/criticism - the earlier the better :)

Comment: `myProject.js` shouldn't export anything.

Comment: If I understand correctly, myProject.js can be effectively replaced by index.js, as its purpose previously was only to group all other objects under one namespace. True?

Comment: @veratti: Correct.  When using modules, there is no concept of namespaces at all.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. My understanding has greatly improved :) I am trying not to be giddy about you answering my question - I have followed you on Twitter for a while and am a fan! You've made my day with your help!